# Big O, Theta, and big Omega notation

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

Based on my understanding, big O is essentially similar to theta notation but can include anything bigger than the given function (e.g. `n^3 = O(n^4), n^3 = O(n^5)`, etc.), and big Omega includes anything smaller than the given function (`n^3 = Ω(n^2`), etc.).

However, my professor said the other day that `n^0.79 = Ω(n^0.8)`, while he was doing an exercise that involved the master theorem.

Why/how is this true when `n^0.8` is larger than `n^0.79`?

Comment: n^0.79 is not Omega(n^0.8).

Comment: I second David here, your professor must have meant n^0.79 = O(n^0.8).

Comment: Just to prove that n^0.79 is not Omega(n^0.8): for every constant c > 0, there exist infinitely many n such that n^0.79 < cn^0.8 (i.e., all n > c^-100).

Answer (score 0):

You have big O and big Omega backwards.  Big O is everything the "same" or smaller than the function.

Comment: Yes, the wording is backwards, but the examples in the parantheses are correct.

Comment: Sorry if I worded it ambiguously, but yes, the examples are what I know to be true.